# Use `\big\vert f(x) \big\vert` or `\big\lvert f(x) \big\rvert` or `\bigl\lvert f(x) \bigr\rvert`

Tags: math-mode

For typesetting the absolute value of $f(x)$, which of the following gives the proper spacing about "$f(x)$"?

```
$\big\vert f(x) \big\vert$
$\big\lvert f(x) \big\rvert$
$\bigl\lvert f(x) \bigr\rvert$
```

Comment: Usually, I  once typed `\bigl|...\bigr|`, but it is even shorter to  define an `\abs` command with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools` and type `\abs[\big]{...}` (and it is semantically better).

Comment: @Bernard I am using an online editor that does not allow users to modify the preamble. (`mathtools` must be in the preamble.) Is there any difference in using the three commands in the post?

Comment: never use `\big` in a document, it is just the internal shared code for `\bigl` and `\bigr`, not something to use directly. `big` is also far too big for f(x), `\lvert f{x}\rvert` would be better.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\big` (or maybe `\Big`) has its use cases: for instance, one can use `f\big|_{A}` to denote restriction or “evaluation at”. Besides such cases, most of the times one should use `\bigl` (opening), `\bigr` (closing) or else `\bigm` (relation).

Comment: @egreg yes I know but there is a tex tradition to give simple rules first, and break them later:-)

Comment: @David Carlisle If I am to take the absolute value of `f(x)` and not `-f(x)`, why do you say to use `\lvert fx) \rvert` when `\vert f(x) \vert` will give the same display?  (From the response provided by Mico, I know that `\lvert -fx) \rvert` when `\vert -f(x) \vert` will display differently.)  Is it just good typesetting habits?

Comment: There are other differences, the outer spacing is affected not just the inner eg an operator so `\log\vert x \vert` is not the same as `\log\lvert x \rvert` (actually you might prefer the first spacing in that case, but they are different)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You asked,

> which of the following gives the proper spacing about "$f(x)$"?

```
$\big\vert f(x) \big\vert$
$\big\lvert f(x) \big\rvert$
$\bigl\lvert f(x) \bigr\rvert$
```

First off, you actually left off the following, relevant option:

```
$\bigl\vert f(x) \bigr\vert$
```

Second, it so happens that if the "math atom" (to use some TeX jargon) that is placed between the vertical bars is `f(x)`, then all four options produce the exact same output.

Third, does the preceding finding mean that writing

```
$\big\vert <some math atom> \big\vert$
```

is always typographically ok -- and maybe even best because it's the simplest of the four options? *Not at all!* To verify this, consider the following MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\lvert' and '\rvert' directives
\begin{document}
\obeylines
$\big\vert   -1 \big\vert$ 
$\big\lvert  -1 \big\rvert$
$\bigl\vert  -1 \bigr\vert$
$\bigl\lvert -1 \bigr\rvert$
\end{document}
```

and its output:

[image]

Only the latter two are *typographically* correct, as they treat the `-` ("minus") symbols as a *unary* rather than as a binary operator.

In short, `\bigl\vert <some math atom> \bigr\vert` is definitely better than `\big\vert <some math atom> \big\vert`, typographically speaking, as it produces the correct spacing in all cases.

A final remark, prompted by a comment from barbara beeton: For the code examples used here, it's *not* necessary to increase the size of the vertical bars. However, I'm assuming your real use case involves expressions such as `$\bigl\vert -\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx \bigr\vert$`.

Comment: I appreciate your careful explanation. As you saw, I did not get such an explanation from the pdf file that was suggested to me.

Comment: You might also mention that any "big" is definitely not needed in the case of `$-1$` or `$f(x)` since it won't make any difference in the size of the verts.  "big" should probably also *not* be used for, say, `$f(x^2)$` -- it's overkill.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - You're right, of course. I was *hoping* -- but didn't say so outright -- that the OP's real use case involves taking absolute values of something (typographically) bigger than `f(x)` or `-1`. I'll edit my answer to put in a remark to this effect.

Comment: Well, you forget the easiest `\bigl|-1\bigr|`. ;-) Similarly, one can abbreviate `\bigl\langle` into `\bigl<` and `\bigr\rangle` into `\bigr>`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `\big?` *does* make a difference: `\bigl|-1\bigr|` is different from `\lvert-1\rvert`. No difference in size would be with `\left|-1\right|`.

Comment: @Mico I am responding to your added comment to your post. I have used `\bigl\vert f(x) \bigr\vert` in code. (I do not use `\bigl` and `\bigr` for typesetting the absolute value of `g(x)`.) Why should I avoid using `\bigl` and `\bigr` in typesetting the absolute value of `f(x)`?

Comment: @user74973 - Sorry the purpose of my follow-up comment wasn't clear enough. One of the main principles of fine math typography is *striking a visual balance* among all elements of a math formula. What does that mean, though? For me, it means that all relevant parts of the formula should be given roughly equal visual prominence, so that nothing gets overlooked. Please compare the outputs of `$\bigl\vert f(x)\bigr\vert$` and `$\lvert f(x)\rvert$`: In the former formula, the vertical bars are unnecessarily dominant, visually speaking -- it lacks "balance".

Comment: @user74973 - Continuing the preceding train of thought: Next, compare the outputs of `$\bigl\vert -\frac{1}{2}\bigr\vert$` and  `$\lvert -\frac{1}{2}\rvert$`: now it's the latter formula that lacks balance, as the fraction term dominates the absolute-value bars, which are in fact so puny as to almost disappear...

Comment: OK. I understand your comment about "visual balance." So, I guess that I should use `\lvert -f(x) \rvert` just as I should use `\lvert -1 \rvert`.

Comment: I like your comment that `\bigl\vert  -1 \bigr\vert` and `\bigl\lvert  -1 \bigr\rvert`  "are typographically correct, as they treat the - ("minus sign") symbol as a unary rather than as a binary operator."  I guess `\lvert -1 \rvert` also treats the minus sign as a unary operator. Do either `| -1 |` or `\vert -1 \vert` treat the minus sign as a unary operator?

Comment: Is it fair to conclude from your response that even though `|f(x)|`, `\vert f(x) \vert`, and `\lvert f(x) \rvert` all typeset the absolute value of `f(x)` identically, the latter is preferred for consistency of coding - in case I am foolish enough to want to take the absolute value of `-f(x)` somewhere in the same file?

Comment: @user74973 - As is explained in far more detail in [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/510786/5001), the whole point of using `\lvert` and `\rvert` (instead of `|` or `\vert`) when typesetting the absolute value a <math atom> is to give TeX the information it needs to get its typesetting job done properly in all circumstances, i.e., regardless of the specific form of the <math atom>. You also asked, "Do either `| -1 |` or `\vert -1 \vert` treat the minus sign as a unary operator? **NO**. Otherwise, why invent the macros `\lvert` and `\rvert`?

Comment: If I am typesetting a Calculus test that has only one absolute value function on it - like the absolute value of `\sin2x` - will `|\sin2x|`, `\vert \sin2x \vert`, and `\lvert \sin2x \rvert` all be rendered the same?

Comment: @user74973 - Short answer: NO. Longer (louder!?) answer: **NO**. Still longer answer: Of the three options, only `\lvert\sin2x\rvert` is typographically correct.

Answer (score 7):

#### Differences when `\big` is used

There's no difference at all between `\big|`, `\big\vert` and `\big\lvert`. The reason is that `\big` (and also its siblings `\Big`, `\bigg` and `\Bigg`) make an ordinary symbol out of the following delimiter, after forcing it to be a larger size.

Thus whether you use `|`, `\vert` or `\lvert` after `\big` is immaterial. In the first case TeX looks at the `\delcode` of `|`, which is `"26A30C`. In the second case it looks at the definition of `\vert`, which is `\delimiter"026A30C`; the definition of `\lvert` is `\delimiter 69640972` (hexadecimal `"426A30C`). If we supplement this with the information that the `\mathcode` of `|` is `"026A` we have the whole picture.

#### How does `\big` work?

When we say `\big<symbol>`, the `<symbol>` can be either a character or a control sequence; if it is a character, it must have a positive `\delcode`; if it is a control sequence it must be a macro whose meaning starts with `\delimiter` followed by a 27 bit number. These are the same requirements for something following `\left` and not by chance: indeed `\big<symbol>` is realized by doing something like

```
{\left<symbol><empty box>\right.}
```

where the `<empty box>` has suitable vertical size to trigger `\left` choosing a larger variant. (I'm hiding some detail, as usual.) The braces around the construction make the object an ordinary symbol.

#### What's the difference between `\vert` and `|`?

None, as far as the behavior in math formulas is concerned. They behave as ordinary symbols.

#### What's the difference between `\lvert` and `\vert`?

This is a big one! `\lvert` is considered as an opening atom; its companion `\rvert` is a closing atom. The commands have been introduced by `amsmath` (not by the LaTeX kernel), in order to avoid bad spacing: just considering the output of

```
|-1|+\vert\sin x\vert
```

versus

```
\lvert-1\rvert+\lvert\sin x\rvert
```

clears up the matter. In the first formula, using `|` instead of `\vert` or conversely produces the same output.

#### How does `\bigl` work?

With `\bigl<symbol>`, TeX will do

```
\mathopen{\left<symbol><empty box>\right.}
```

that is, the same as before, but with `\mathopen` acting on the object, which makes it to be spaced correctly. Again it's immaterial whether we use

```
\bigl|  \bigl\vert  \bigl\lvert
```

The action of `\bigr` is similar: with `\bigr<symbol>` we obtain

```
\mathclose{\left<symbol><empty box>\right.}
```

which is appropriate for a closing atom.

#### There's also `\bigm`

If we do `\bigm<symbol>` we obtain

```
\mathrel{\left<symbol><empty box>\right.}
```

which is appropriate for the `<symbol>` used as a relation symbol. For instance, it would be correct to use

```
\bigl\{ x\in X \bigm| <condition> \bigr\}
```

in case we need larger fences. Again, `\bigm|`, `\bigm\vert`, `\bigm\lvert` or even `\bigm\rvert` are exactly the same.

#### Should I use `\lvert` and `\rvert` after `\bigl` and `\bigr`?

**Yes**, we should. But laziness has its merits, so the simpler `\bigl|` is handier.

#### Is `\big|` banned from use?

Not at all! If we want a larger vertical bar to denote restriction of a function or evaluation at a point, we can certainly use `\big|`, say for

```
f\big|_{A}
f(x)\big|_{x=0}
```

(in the second case, perhaps `\Big|` would be better, but it's a matter of taste).

#### Graphical examples

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
Input & Output \\
\midrule
\verb!|-1|+\vert\sin x\vert! &
  $|-1|+\vert\sin x\vert$ \\
\verb!\lvert-1\rvert+\lvert\sin x\rvert! &
  $\lvert-1\rvert+\lvert\sin x\rvert$ \\
\midrule
\verb!\big|-1\big|+\big\vert\sin x\big\vert! &
  $\big|-1\big|+\big\vert\sin x\big\vert$ \\
\verb!\bigl\lvert-1\bigr\rvert+\bigl\lvert\sin x\bigr\rvert! &
  $\bigl\lvert-1\bigr\rvert+\bigl\lvert\sin x\bigr\rvert$ \\
\verb!\bigl|-1\bigr|+\bigl|\sin x\bigr|! &
  $\bigl|-1\bigr|+\bigl|\sin x\bigr|$ \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You said "`\lvert` is considered as an opening atom." Does that change the spacing before the vertical bar in the pdf file?  Which of `f\bigl|_{x=0}`, `f\bigl\vert_{x=0}`, `f\bigl\lvert_{x=0}` is preferred?

Comment: @user74973 As I wrote in my answer, `\big` is good for this application

Comment: What is the difference between `f\big|_{x=0}` and `f\bigl|_{x=0}`?

Comment: @user74973 `\big|` is an ordinary atom; `\bigl|` is an opening atom that can affect spacing with what follows.

Comment: Will the subscript `x=0` will be typeset further from the vertical bar with `\big|` than with `\bigl|`?  What happens with spacing with what precedes? Will the distance between the `f` and the vertical bar be the same with `\big|` as it is with `\bigl|`?

Comment: @user74973 Try for yourself `\big|_{x=0}\sin y` and `\bigl|_{x=0}\sin y`. The choice would more likely be betwee `\big` and `\bigr`; `\bigl` is out of the question. For this application `\big` is better.